# Red wire in a junction box

Tags: junction-box

I am removing/eliminating a switch and light from upstairs and traced the wire to a basement junction box. The white wire from that romex is connected to a single red wire from circuit box. If I remove the romex from the old switch, what do I do with the red wire? Can I cap it or should I connect it to another set
If wires in the junction box?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Note that Code has certain requirements for switch locations. Do not eliminate a switch that happens to be required.

Comment: It looks like red is a hot and is feeding the switch loop you are removing. It comes back with the black connected to the other leg in the bottom right. I assume that powers the light and you will be removing that as well? If so just cap the red like the other's have suggested

Answer (score 2):

If this is understood correctly, The white wire connected to the red will be eliminated, but the red will remain.
If this is correct, you may cap the red and leave it in the box.
It probably was part of a switch loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're disconnecting any ends cap them.

If you're eliminating a switch connect the wires that used to connect to the switch circuit together.

Answer (score 0):

Remove separate the black wire from the others, the ground (bare copper) from the other ground wires, and white wire from the red wire. Re-use the red wire nuts on the resulting wires.

I have marked up your photo for clarity. The red wire is connected to the white wire (marked with yellow arrow). The hot (black) wire is marked by the orange arrow. The blue arrow points to the molex you are removing.

When you are reusing the red wire nut on the now dangling red wire, you may need to get a [smaller one (yellow color)](https://www.electrical101.com/wire-connectors.html) to get it to catch securely.

[image: red wire]